# Why is my Seive of Eratosthenes Algorithm implementation running into infinite loop?

Tags: algorithm, loops, sieve-of-eratosthenes, sieve

I was implementing Sieve's Algorithm for finding Prime Numbers up to n. I am unable to find out why is it running into infinite loop.

Here I'm giving the code snippet. Please help.

```
for(int j=2;j<=Math.sqrt(n);j++){
  if(a[j]==true){
     int x=0;
     for(int p=(j*j+x*j); p<=n;x++){
        a[p]=true;
     }
  }
}
```

Comment: When you correct it, keep in mind that an addition is cheaper than a multiplication and write the inner cycle as `for(int p=j*j; p<=n;p+=j)`.

Comment: Also, shouldn't the sieve take the first number not marked as composite and mark all its multiples as composite?

Comment: @biziclop "shouldn't the sieve take the first number not marked as composite" where do you think this doesn't happen? (the first `p` that is non-composite is indeed `j*j` - any lower than that would have been marked as composite when `j` have had lower values)

Comment: I'm very stupid this morning but isn't `j*j` by definition composite for any `j>1`? :)

Comment: You may want to update your title to "Sieve of Eratosthenes" so more people realize what this question is about. This algorithm is not called "Sieve's Algorithm".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your inner loop is checking p but never changing it

Answer (score 1):

Some optimisations suggestions:

```
// When j is 2, the bitwise (2 & 1) will be 0, so the cycle increments by 1
// When j is odd (from 3 and above), the cycle goes in steps of 2 
// (thus exploring only odd numbers)
// As a result, this cycle is twice as faster than the one progressing
// in increments of 1 
// See here --------------------V
for(int j=2;j<=Math.sqrt(n);j+=(j & 1 ? 2 : 1)) {
  if(a[j]==true){
     // int x=0; // what for?
     // a sum is cheaper than a multiplication
     // Here --V and here --V
     for(int p=j*j; p<=n;p+=j){
        a[p]=true;
     }
  }
}
```